# How do I write a function that consumes columns in a query in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a query of the form:

```
select lR cor mR from j
```

This works fine, and I get a single number.

When I try to use my custom function:

```
center:{x - avg raze x}

fit1:{
  xc: 0^center[x];
  yc: 0^center[y];
  beta: raze yc lsq xc;
  intercept: (avg raze y) - (beta * avg raze x);
  raze beta
  }


select fit1[lR;mR] from j
```

I get a column of numbers, as it appears to have applied the function row-wise, rather than column wise.

Two questions:

- How can I go about fixing this?
- Is it possible to see the source code of `cor` so I can learn, or is it closed?

**Edit**

```
t:([] date:tt; x:xx; y:yy)

t          x y
--------------
2021.01.01 0 4
2021.01.02 1 4
2021.01.03 2 4
2021.01.04 3 4
2021.01.05 4 4
2021.01.06 5 4
2021.01.07 6 4
2021.01.08 7 4
2021.01.09 8 4
2021.01.10 9 4

select fit1[x;y] from t
```

Updated now with a proper example:

```
center:{x - avg raze x}

fit1:{
  xc: 0^center[x];
  yc: 0^center[y];
  beta: raze yc lsq xc;
  intercept: (avg raze y) - (beta * avg raze x);
  raze beta
  }

tt: 2021.01.01 + til 10
xx: 9h$til 10
yy: ((xx)*3) + 4
t:([] date:tt; x:xx; y:yy)
    date       x y
---------------
2021.01.01 0 4
2021.01.02 1 7
2021.01.03 2 10
2021.01.04 3 13
2021.01.05 4 16
2021.01.06 5 19
2021.01.07 6 22
2021.01.08 7 25
2021.01.09 8 28
2021.01.10 9 31

q)fit1[enlist xx;enlist yy]
,3f
q)select fit1[x;y] from t
y
----
-4.5
-3.5
-2.5
-1.5
-0.5
0.5
1.5
2.5
3.5
4.5
```

d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there is enough information provided to help give a definitive fix for your issue but your function creates an `intercept` variable which it doesn't use in the final return. This line is currently pointless. Your custom function is not designed to return an atom like `cor`.
2. Some keywords provide the underlying k code if you just enter the keyword in the q console. If you get the key word back then it is hidden but for cor and cov the equivalent code is provided in the docs.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cor/
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cov/

Comment: When you say 'my function isn't designed to return at atom", the final line `raze beta` should just be a singular float?

The issue I'm having is the builtin's like `count` and `sum` seem to receive lists as params, where as my function seem to receive row-wise atoms.

Comment: Your function will receive the entire column as lR and mR. You use each/each-both to do "row-wise". raze will return a list if beta is a list which it must be. I don't know what your `center` function is doing and you haven't provided sample inputs

Comment: I've added an example. For anyone looking; the trick was to figure out whether things need to be enlisted or not before passing them in.

Answer (score 0):

1. To answer your first question you can do:

```
q)fit1[j`lR;j`mR]
```